# How to split a dataframe by date and assemble a new set of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, coordinates

I have data in the following format as a data frame:

```
* Date    Lat    Long      ID
* May 4    30      31      1 
* May 4    30      31      2
* May 4    30      31      3
* May 5    30      31      4
* May 5    31      31      5
* May 5    31      31      6
* May 6    31      31      7
* May 6    33      31      8 
* May 6    31      31      9
```

I want to be able to extract data frames by date and apply the following function from the 'fossil' package

```
create.lats(x, loc="locality", long="longitude", lat="latitude")
```

I've used split to break up the data by date but this converts everything into a list

```
split(mydata, with(mydata, (date)), drop = TRUE)
```

then I need to transform each of these individual lists back to data frames with their original headers.

I guess I'll need a loop to do this? Unfortunately this where I'm stuck so any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the create.labs function applied to data frame by factor and returned into a data frame consisting of the original data frame plus the new output:

```
rm(list=ls())
require(fossil)
df = data.frame("Date"=sample(LETTERS[1:4],100,replace=TRUE), 
                "Lat"= sample(30:35,100,replace=TRUE),
                "Long"= sample(30:35,100,replace=TRUE),
                "ID" = sample(1:5,100,replace=TRUE) )
endresult = do.call("rbind",by(df, df$Date, 
                              function(x) 
                              { data.frame(cbind(x,create.lats(x,loc="Date", long="Long", lat="Lat")),stringsAsFactors=F) } ))
rownames(endresult)=NULL
```

you can also do this with `ddply` in the plyr package. I would recommend using `dput` in your original question to make it easier for people to look at your data.

Comment: Hi @Hans Roggeman , thanks for responding. I tried your code but I get the error: cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame

Comment: you must have missed a `(` or something, I just did a copy & paste and it worked. Try a copy and paste of the code. If it does not work on your data give us the output of `dput(sample_data)` to look at your data.